# ECS scheduled task with specific Fargate platform version (on CDK )

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-cdk

I'm trying to schedule a task on ECS (running on Fargate), via CDK. When it runs, my task uses the `LATEST` platform version ([which is currently 1.3.0](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/platform_versions.html), despite 1.4.0 having been released). I'd like to use version 1.4.0, but I can't see a way to specify that in the CDK objects - it only seems to be supported when creating a [FargateService](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ecs.FargateService.html#platformversion), whereas I'm using a `FargateTaskDefinition`. Does anyone know if this is possible? (It's possible via the direct API, and via the console).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to upgrade your aws-cdk first.
`npm install -g aws-cdk`

Then upgrade the package.json
`npx npm-check -u`

the latest "@aws-cdk/aws-ecs": 1.72 allows you to specify the platform version in ecs task:
new EcsTask({
...
platformVersion: FargatePlatformVersion.VERSION1_4
})

Comment: Interestingly, AWS have now set `LATEST` to `1.4.0` anyway ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/platform_versions.html)), although at time of writing I'm not seeing that in my CDK deployments.